# Ansible, how to check if a variable is not null?

Tags: ansible

I have this var I a role that I use to add authorized keys to a linux user, so foo can either be a string with a single ssh public key or a list of multiple public keys.

By default `foo` is defined but empty so it can be tested even if the user doesn't set it, that way no related tasks are done if it's empty.

I'd normaly use `when: foo` or `when: not foo` and it was working great, except that now ansible trow a depreciation warning saying :

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: evaluating None as a bare variable, this
>   behaviour will go away and you might need to add |bool to the
>   expression in the future. Also see CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS configuration
>   toggle.. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation
>   warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in
>   ansible.cfg.

I tried `when: foo|bool` as mentionned but it returns `false` every time the variable is filled with a string that's not yes, true, Yes...

`foo is defined` doesn't work since the var is defined

`foo != ""` doesn't work because the var is null not a empty string

foo | length > 0 doesn't work because null doesn't have a length

I'm honestly out of ideas here.

Answer (score 20):

I think the answer is right there in the error. "evaluating None as a bare variable" suggests that foo evaluated to None. So you need:

`when: foo != None`

Answer (score 10):

The thing you are looking for is [the `default` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables), which helpfully has an alias `d` as in `when: foo | d("")` or even `when: foo | d(False)`

Just watch out, `default` normally **only** replaces `null` or `None`, and not the pythontic idea of truthiness. For that, you'll want to provide it a second argument `foo | default("something-else", true)` which works in the cases that `foo` is either `null` or `""` (or likely 0 also)

Answer (score 0):

In my case default filter doesn't works. Just not defaulting defined but unset variable.

There is a working solution

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    foo:
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure foo is set
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: "Foo is not set"
      when: foo is undefined or foo == None or foo | length == 0
    - name: Show var
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: foo
```

There is 3 checks: does `foo` undefined, does `foo` set and does `foo` not empty string.